# Can't set keyframes from custom operator panel

Tags: animation, keyframes, operator, panel

It's a floating Operator like this

With use_property_decorate and use_property_split enabled, the 'Animate Property' dot does nothing. Clicking it will immediately gray out. Right-clicking on the property and select "insert keyframe" has the same result.

Also, the object eyedropper is not working too

[image]